# About a person count limitation of person-group

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

I trying to use the Face API of Microsoft Cognitive Service.
And want to know about a person count limitation of person-group.

How much peoples can exist into a person-group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Free tier subscriptions have a limit of 1,000 persons per Person Group and 1,000 persons total per subscription. The S0 tier subscriptions have these limits: 10,000 Persons per Person Group, 100M Persons total and 1M Person Groups per subscription [visit this link for more detail](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f3039523c)

Answer (score 1):

You can have up to 1000 persons per persongroup.  The documentation is [here](https://dev.projectoxford.ai/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f3039523c).